# ¿Como llamar a una funcion en un script que contiene una ventana Tkinter y varias funciones desde otra ventana Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

Tengo un script principal formado por una ventana Tkinter, y quiero que al pulsar un botón abra otro script que contiene otra ventana Tkinter ademas de sus funciones.

Probé de la siguiente manera:
script principal:

```
from nombre_modulo import *

def abrir_modulo():
   funcion_modulo_importado()
```

De esa manera no importa las funciones que contiene el script, solo abre la ventana.

Answer (score 1):

La manera correcta de importar cualquier función de otro script es importar las funciones del archivo *.py teniendo en cuenta que usted no debe poder el nombre del archivo con la extensión *.py porque esto genera error, usted importa ese archivo como modulo, por lo tanto la manera más sencilla en mi opinión personal es solo importar de ese archivo los nombres de la función sin agregar paréntesis al importar.

Este sería un ejemplo de una función cualquiera en otro archivo de script, en este caso se llama FileEjemplo.py:

```
def EjemploFuncion():
     print('Ejemplo función...')
```

Este es un ejemplo importando el archivo y su(s) funciones dependiendo de lo que usted agregue en la función, en este caso el archivo se llama FileEjemplo.py:

```
from FileEjemplo import EjemploFuncion # FileEjemplo.py se importa como modulo
```

Si son varias funciones:

```
from FileEjemplo import EjemploFuncion, EjemploFuncion2 # Dependiendo de las funciones que usted quiere reutilizar del archivo usted las pone al momento de importar
```

**Nota:** Tenga en cuenta que los archivos deben estar en el mismo directorio para evitar errores al momento de importar.

Cuando usted agregue el evento del botón, la instrucción que usted va ejecutar es la que usted importó del modulo, ejemplo: `tk.Button(..., command=EjemploFuncion)`